# Is there any reason in writing dict() instead of {}?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've heard that construction `{}` works much faster then `dict()`. But does that mean I have to write `{}` everywhere ?

Comment: FWIW, `{}` is a literal so it can be created when the script is compiled to bytecode, whereas `dict()` calls the `dict` object constructor at runtime. Apart from efficiency considerations, it's generally considered better style to use a literal than an equivalent function / class call.

Answer (score 0):

Just use {} and [] and forget about dict() and list()

Comment: There are plenty good reasons to explicitely use `dict` and `list` (and `set`, `str` or any other builtin type having both a literal and normal syntax).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you give me some examples ?

Comment: @faoxis: building a dict from a list of key:value pairs, building a list from an iterable, etc...

Comment: dict = {el:0 for el in a} ...